# Delegate.CreateDelegate with optionals parameters

Tags: c#

I want to create a method that take any method on parameters and return a Delegate which is the perfect match of it, in order to store it and use DynamicInvoke on it with an array of parameters later.

This method, for now:

```
private Delegate CreateDelegate(Delegate method)
{
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(method.GetType(), method.Target, method.Method);
}
```

It works fine, but when I try on a method with optionals parameters (I put in the array of DynamicInvoke Type.Missing for each optionals parameters), I got an exception:

`System.ArgumentException: Missing parameter does not have a default value`

If I cast my method to the right delegate before calling CreateDelegate on it, that works fine, but I don't want to create a delegate for each method...

Here is a fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEPvyj

(Edit) Here is the real fiddle, my bad:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/sf3X9G

Comment: I recreate your code in a Console App in Vs 2022. It runs successfully without error. I checked in with .Net 7.0 and .Net 6.0 and it was OK. can you tell me which dontnet version you use?

Comment: You already have a delegate, why do you need to make a new one?  Just store the delegate you already have.

Comment: I use .Net 7.0, and I've the same error as in my fiddle:
`System.ArgumentException: Missing parameter does not have a default value`  

@Servy : good point, I simplified my code, CreateDelegate is in fact CreateDelegate<T> where T : Delegate

Comment: default values are a compile time thing for method calls.

Comment: @DanielA.White, No, they are a runtime thing too. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```cs
delegate void MyDelegate(object[] args);

private void InvokeFromDelegate(Delegate invokable, params object[] parameters)
{
    ((MyDelegate) invokable)(parameters);
}   

private Delegate CreateDelegate(Delegate del)
{
    var parameters = del.Method.GetParameters();
    var callback = Delegate.CreateDelegate(del.GetType(), del.Target, del.Method);

    return new MyDelegate(args =>
    {
        var realArgs = new object[parameters.Length];
        Array.Copy(args, 0, realArgs, 0, args.Length);
        for (int i = args.Length; i < parameters.Length; ++i)
        {
            realArgs[i] = parameters[i].DefaultValue;
        }
        
        callback.DynamicInvoke(realArgs);
    });
}
```

And remove `Type.Missing` from the invocations.

Your second `InvokeFromDelegate()` will fail, but you didn't want it anyway.

Comment: That's awful, it does the missing parameter search over again for each call.  The code would be not much more complicated, and much better runtime performance, to construct an expression tree (`MethodCallExpression`) compiled to a delegate

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'd love to see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround whitch not really answer the initiale question, but it does the job I want.

I call the InvokeFromDelegate without optionals parameters, and then I fill the missing parameters with reflection.

```
private void InvokeFromDelegate(Delegate invokable, params object[] parameters)
{
    System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] expectedParameters = invokable.Method.GetParameters();
    object[] invokationParameters = parameters;
    if (expectedParameters.Length > parameters.Length)
    {
        invokationParameters = new object[expectedParameters.Length];
        Array.Copy(parameters, invokationParameters, parameters.Length);
        for (int i = parameters.Length; i < expectedParameters.Length; ++i)
        {
            invokationParameters[i] = expectedParameters[i].HasDefaultValue ? expectedParameters[i].DefaultValue : null;
        }
    }       
    invokable.DynamicInvoke(invokationParameters);
}
```

Here is the working fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/hUhxss

Thanks all for helping me :)